# Clear all fields in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a form with about 25 fields and some dropdowns too, I want to have a clean button that resets all the form, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This is just a thought, not sure if it works or not, for all entry boxes you can bind it to array of string for example entry 1 is binded to string[1], entry 2 to string[2] and so on. On clear button you can clear the array that should sort all entry boxes, I am not sure of any easy way for dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controls are bound to an object with two way binding you can iterate over the properties and clear the values using the code below.

```
    private async void btnClear_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyData data = (MyData)this.BindingContext;
        await ClearProperties(data);
    }

    private async Task ClearProperties<T>(T instance)
    {
        await ClearProperties(typeof(T), instance);
    }

    private async Task ClearProperties(Type classType, object instance)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in classType.GetRuntimeProperties()) 
        {
            object value = null;
            try
            {
                value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            if (value != null && property.PropertyType != typeof(String))
                await ClearProperties(property.PropertyType, value);
            else if (value != null && (String)value != "")
                property.SetValue(instance, null);
        }
    }
```

This loops through the properties and their properties and if it is a String and it is not empty it will set the value to null. If you are binding to something other than a String you may have to modify it a bit.

Comment: MyData can be viewmodel?

Comment: I tried but I am not able to clear the values stored in control.

Answer (score 2):

For example I have the same situation but all of entries and dropdowns are tied by a model through the BindingContext.

When clearing the form the only thing that is needed is to instantiate the model again and bind  that to BindingContext.

```
    private void ClearForm_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        _viewModel = (ViewModel)BindingContext;
    }
```