# Xamarin Forms Clear All Entries

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

Is there a way to clear all entries in an Xamarin.Forms app? I checked this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142029/clear-all-fields-in-xamarin-forms/46771999#46771999) but it did not help.

Comment: Yes.   Loop through all of them and clear their values, or clear the model properties they are bound to.  But there is no built in function that will magically do this for you.

Comment: For the link provided, he just created another view model instance, so every text value binded on the page will be cleared to default. And what do you mean by "did not help", any code to post.

Comment: @Shaw I think he is using MVVM right? I'm not using it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jason can u please add some code snippet? I was searching for a way to get all entries and loop through them or giving them a class like HTML and clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should work

You can iterate through all the child views in your layout and clear the entries inside of it.

If you are using XAML, give your layout a name so you could access it in the backend code

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyForm">
    <Label Text="Anything"/>
    <Entry />
    <Entry />
    <Entry />
    <Button Text="Clear" x:Name="Clear" Clicked="Clear_Clicked" />

</StackLayout>
```

Then in your Backend:

```
private void Clear_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (View view in MyForm.Children)
    {

        if(view is Entry)
        {
            (view as Entry).Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used @Bassies code, modified to clear entries from layout dynamically. So, you do not need to add reference in code behind. This method will loop through each items and clear text. So, while comparing @Bassies way, this dynamic method will take little more time to process. But it will be negligible time as single page view will not contain huge amount of views (like 10000 or more)

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var child = this.Content as Layout;
            if (child != null)
            {
                ProcessLayoutChildren(child);
            }
        }

        public void ProcessLayoutChildren(Layout child)
        {
            foreach (var item in child.Children)
            {
                var layout = item as Layout;
                if (layout != null)
                {
                    ProcessLayoutChildren(layout);
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearEntry(item);
                }
            }

            void ClearEntry(Element entryElement)
            {
                var entry = entryElement as Entry;
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    entry.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sounds like @Houssem answers. I upvoted it but did not marked it as accepted since he answered first. thank u

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! I just added the condition `if (item.GetType() == typeof(Entry))` inside the `else` statement, so the code won't try to clear elements that are not entries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the right way but an example how it works on 1 Page.

You might want to change it , but give's an idea how it works

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
        <Label Text="Clear All" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
    </Frame>

    <Entry x:Name="Nr1" />
    <Entry x:Name="Nr2" />
    <Entry x:Name="Nr3" />
    <Button Text="Clear" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

</StackLayout>
```

And
Make a List and give the Entry's a Name , i use Nr1, Nr2 and Nr3 but only for example.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<Entry> entry = new List<Entry>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        entry.Clear();
        entry.Add(Nr1);
        entry.Add(Nr2);
        entry.Add(Nr3);

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in entry)
        {

            entry.Text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Made a small example , you can find it here . https://github.com/borisoprit/Clearentry

Comment: I think this works but did not accept it since instead of putting them in a list and loop on them then i can at once clear them. but thank u for your help

Comment: @Sam no problem , i used it in my App because there where 3 of 20 Entry's that i did not want to clear . That is why i use a list.